# Existence of primes less than double a previous prime (two steps back) - extending Bertrand?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Say we have three sequential primes: $p_1, p_2, p_3$

I know by Bertrand's postulate that $p_2<2p_1$

However, what I wonder is for $p_1>7$ if the following is always true:

$p_3<2p_1$

A simulation shows it to be true at least for primes up to 100 000

Comment: So $p_{n+2}<2p_n$, right? See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) under "generalisations" of Bertrand $p_{n+1}<2p_n$.

Comment: Yes, that does seem to work. If I understand it correctly, in this case (according to the notation on that page) $n=2$ and so $R_n=11$ and $\pi (R_n)=5$ so $k=5$ and thus for $i>5$ you get $2p_{i-2} > p_i$ which is what I want, but for $p>11$ which is fine.